# Pentagonal Theorem and Ferrers Diagrams

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, graph-theory

I have this question about the "Bijective Proof" on [The Pentagonal number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_number_theorem).

What do they mean by the right most 45degree line? In this example it would be the second and third row?

o o o o o o o o o o

o o o o o o

o o o o o

According to the prescription, since s=2 and m=5 so that m>s, we have to take these circles and add them to the bottom i.e.

o o o o o o o o o o

o o o o o

o o o o

o o

Right, now we have m=2 and s=2 and since m<=s, the inversion operation should be to add these m=2 elements at the bottom back to the top, which gives

o o o o o o o o o o o

o o o o o o

o o o o

and is not the original Ferrers diagram. So what do they mean?

Comment: A side note : it's unfortunate that the Wikipedia page on pentagonal number theorem doesnt mention the mathematician who has had the non-evident idea to refer to Ferrer's diagrams. See for that https://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/PentagonalNumbers.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "right most 45 degree line" always starts at the right hand end of the longest row, but it might only be of length $1$. This is the case in your diagram, where we have a bijection between $\{ 10,6,5 \}$ with an odd number of distinct parts and $\{ 9, 6, 5, 1 \}$ with an even number of distinct parts.